# Perl s/../../ not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

The code is a bit convoluted, but I simplified it a bit. I know I could easily do this:

```
$svn_module s#.*/##;
```

And pull off just the end of the module. But something strange is going on here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $svn_module = "http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/trunk/SessionController";
print qq(DEBUG: svn_module = "$svn_module"\n);
$svn_module =~ s#^.*(branches/.+?/)|(trunk)/##;
print qq(DEBUG: svn_module = "$svn_module"\n);
```

This prints:

```
DEBUG: svn_module = "http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/trunk/SessionController"
DEBUG: svn_module = "http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/SessionController"
```

However, I was expecting:

```
DEBUG: svn_module = "http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/trunk/SessionController"
DEBUG: svn_module = "SessionController"
```

Why does my substitution expression remove `trunk/`, but not the rest of the string up to `trunk/`?

By the way, adding an extra set of parentheses helps:

```
$svn_module =~ s#^.*((branches/.+?/)|(trunk))/##;
```

will work.

By the way, this is Perl 5.8.8. This is a server, and pretty much the version I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered the question by yourself. The | operator has lowest precedence, so putting the additional parentheses is the solution.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure whether you answered my question or not. Obviously the extra set or parentheses worked. However, after reading your answer, I think I do understand. I said basically I was matching either `^.*branches/.+?/` or `trunk`. Not I was matching the entire string from the beginning up to `trunk` as I thought.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it should be this

`s#^.*(?:branches/.+?/|trunk)/##;`

Because, the other way it was a single alternation where the `^.*` are not part
of the second alternation (the one that matched).

```
   ^ .* 
   ( branches/ .+? / )
|  
   ( trunk )
```

Edit: Expanded new regex explained

```
 ^                       # Beginning of string anchor
 .*                      # Optional match as many as possible non-newline character until ..
 (?:                     # Start non-capture grouping
      branches/ .+? /        # 'branches' plus '/' plus 1 or more chars plus '/'
   |  trunk                  # Or, 'trunk'
 )                       # End grouping
```

The equivalent in terms of your original regex is this

```
   ^ .* 
   ( branches/ .+? / )
|  
   ^ .* 
   ( trunk )
```

Comment: I guess my confusion has to do with my `^.*` anchor. I would assume that this is matching from the beginning of the string, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: The `?:` isn't really necessary since I'm not doing group replacement, but I guess it couldn't hurt. The real question is why didn't my anchor work. What was happening was due to me misreading precedence. I was actually matching with `|` either `^.*branches/.+?/` **or** `trunk`.

Comment: @David W. - The `(?:)` is an extension that means non-capture grouping. Capture grouping isin't really necessary in your case since you are just doing a replacement on the entire match (default). The real answer to why your anchor didn't work is it was not factored out of the two alternations you wanted it to apply to. Regex is hardly a language of operator precedence, just of constructs (ie: meta-characters).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, David, but instead of substituting everything up to the last part that you want to get what you want, why not capture just that last part?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $svn_module = "http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/trunk/SessionController";
my ($end_module) = $svn_module =~ /([^\/]+)$/;
print $end_module;
```

Output:

```
SessionController
```

Comment: I want to make sure that I have a `trunk` or `branches/.*?/` in there to make sure I'm looking at a project, and not inside some directory or in tags. Otherwise, I could have done what you mentioned.

Comment: @DavidW. - Ah.  Then why not the adjust the capture accordingly, e.g., `/((?:trunk|branches).+)/`, instead of `s###`?